# How to handle this table overflow?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem with a Bootstrap layout. I do not know how to fix the column overflow for "Private Key:". As you [can see here](https://manageacloud.com/dev/issue-45) (please open with firefox) "Private Key" has a large value and it breaks the content.

How can I fix the width of "Private Key" keeping the website responsive ?

Would you recommend other layout for that content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `white-space: pre-wrap` in the CSS style to wrap long strings without spaces inside `<pre>`.

E.g.

```
#server-credentials-privKey {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

But it seems even in the widest version, the width of the element is not enough to hold the full strings.